# What does the Neko Atsume Apple Watch app do?

Tags: neko-atsume, apple-watch

Neko Atsume recently added Apple Watch support with version 1.9.5.

[image: Update notes for 1.9.5]

Opening the app on my watch shows me a live feed of my yard. Is this all the Apple Watch app does, or is there some way to interact with my yard?

[image: Neko Atsume Apple Watch screenshot]

Comment: Apple Watch might be giving you a gentle hint that it is time for you to go outside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The Apple Watch app only allows you to view what cats are currently in your yard.**

There is no way to interact with your cats while using the Neko Atsume Apple Watch app. You cannot change items, shop, refill food, photograph cats, or receive gifts.

The only things you can do are move the camera around with the touchscreen, and zoom in or out with the digital crown.

This is based on both [online forum posts](https://aminoapps.com/page/neko-atsume-community/7462213/neko-atsume-apple-watch) and my own personal experience using the app over the last 9 months.